# jQuery counter to hide divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, counter

i'm trying to use a jQuery counter to count the number of times the cursor enters a div and if the number is even the div is hidden and if it is odd the div shows up with defined effects, i am having issues since it is the first time i'm using these methods so can anyone help me please? here is the code and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8xjaxm6/2/)

The said script:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/

$(document).ready(function () {

'use strict';
$('.user_ui').hide();

//$(".user").hover(function () {
//  $(".user_ui").slideDown("fast");
//  $('.pre_autor').hide();
//}, function(){
//  $(".user_ui").slideUp("fast");
//  $('.pre_autor').show('fast');
//});


$('.user').mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
    $this.data('count', count);

    if (count % 2 === 0) { 
    $(".user_ui").slideDown("fast");
    $('.pre_autor').hide();
    }
         else { 
        $(".user_ui").slideUp("fast");
        $('.pre_autor').show('fast');   

         }



});
});
```

The css for this part:

```
header {
height: 70px;
background: cadetblue;
}
.main {
font-family: DIN;
font-size: 25px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
color: white;
float: left;
}
.secondary {
font-family: 'DIN';
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 3px;
color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
.user {
font-size: 25px;
float: right;
color: white;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
top: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms;
-moz-transition: all 300ms;
-o-transition: all 300ms;
transition: all 300ms;
}

.user_ui {
width: auto;
height: 200px;
background: cadetblue;
float: right;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
right: 0;
}
.user_ui p {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 3px;
color: white;
font-family: 'DIN-light';
text-align: right;
}
.pre_autor {
font-family: 'DIN';
font-size: 12px;
color: white;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
left: 0;

}
.autor {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: right;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

The Html for this part:

```
<header>

<div class="align_user">
    <p class="pre_autor">Angus Miguel</p>

    <div class="user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
</div>
    <div class="user_ui">

          <p>Angus Miguel</p>
          <p>angusmiguel21@gmail.com</p>
          <img class="autor" src="http://bit.ly/1APlHHT" alt="O Autor" />

    </div>

</header>
```

It is supposed to show the div by hovering the person icon in the top right corner! sorry guys i forgot that!

Comment: what issues are you having mate? On another note, if the div is hidden how is it going to receive focus? The first time the cursor enters the div, the count will be odd, if you hide the div...how's the user going to focus the div again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/e8xjaxm6/3/

You have the right idea but you had a couple of mistakes. You are defining

```
var $count = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10) + 1;
```

but then trying to access it as `count` instead of `$count`. Also you don't have a default value of `data-count` on the element. I added one to the `.user` as `data-count="0"` but you can also add logic to check if `data-count` doesn't exist then default to 0 and add it to the element.

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/e8xjaxm6/4/

I hadn't noticed that. I changed `mouseover` to `mouseenter`. Also changed `if ($count % 2 === 0)` to `if ($count % 2 === 1)`

Comment: it is working pretty fine but when i try to enter the div that shows up it also hides itself, can this be fixed?